# Adding to running total variable?

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to make a resturant menu selector
I have one class for an order and another class thats connected to a select drink menu

My order class (table) has a running total variable. 
Im trying to add the price of an item to the running total but havign trouble with the syntax

```
selectedItem.getPrice();

        Table tbl = new Table();
        tbl.setRunningTotal() + selectedItem.getPrice();
```

am i correct in creating an 'intance' of the table class and then using the set running total 'setter' and adding that to the selected fooditems get price method?

Here is the full 'Table' class

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Table {
   private ArrayList<FoodDrinkController> customers;
   private String tablenumber;
   private ArrayList order;
   private double runningTotal;
   private double totalCalories;

   public Table(ArrayList<FoodDrinkController> customers, String tablenumber, ArrayList order, double runningTotal, double totalCalories) {
      this.customers = customers;
      this.tablenumber = tablenumber;
      this.order = order;
      this.runningTotal = runningTotal;
      this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
   }

   public Table() {

   }

   public ArrayList<FoodDrinkController> getCustomers() {
      return customers;
   }

   public void setCustomers(ArrayList<FoodDrinkController> customers) {
      this.customers = customers;
   }

   public String getTablenumber() {
      return tablenumber;
   }

   public void setTablenumber(String tablenumber) {
      this.tablenumber = tablenumber;
   }

   public ArrayList getOrder() {
      return order;
   }

   public void setOrder(ArrayList order) {
      this.order = order;
   }

   public double getRunningTotal() {
      return runningTotal;
   }

   public void setRunningTotal(double runningTotal) {
      this.runningTotal = runningTotal;
   }

   public double getTotalCalories() {
      return totalCalories;
   }

   public void setTotalCalories(double totalCalories) {
      this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
   }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated
All im trying to do is add the food price attribute to the running total attribute in another class

****EDIT****

This is the SelectDrinkControlleerGUI class

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SelectDrinkControllerGUI extends Application {




    public ListView<FoodDrink> lvDrinks;
    private FoodDrinkController fdc = new FoodDrinkController();
    private Table table;











    public SelectDrinkControllerGUI() {


    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    }


    // Filters the menu items so i just displays drinks in the listview
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("initialize");
        ObservableList<FoodDrink> items = fdc.filterByType(Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        ArrayList<FoodDrink> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        //System.out.println(items);
        for (FoodDrink item : items) {
            stringList.add(item);


        }

        lvDrinks.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(stringList));

    }

    // Button that adds the selected item to the order array
    public void addEntry(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        FoodDrink selectedItem = lvDrinks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        fdc.order.add(selectedItem);

        selectedItem.getPrice();

        Table tbl = new Table();
        tbl.setRunningTotal(tbl.getRunningTotal() + selectedItem.getPrice());

        System.out.println("" + tbl.getRunningTotal());

        System.out.println(fdc.order);



    }
}
```

And this is the FoodDrinkController class which handles all the types of food

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FoodDrinkController {
    private ArrayList<FoodDrink> fullList = new ArrayList<>();




    public ArrayList<FoodDrink> order = new ArrayList<FoodDrink>();








    //constructor with some stuff in it
    public FoodDrinkController(){

        FoodDrink cola = new FoodDrink("Coca Cola", 2.99, Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        FoodDrink pepsi = new FoodDrink("Pepsi", 2.99, Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        FoodDrink lemmonade = new FoodDrink("Lemmonade", 2.99, Global.itemtype.DRINK);
        FoodDrink garlicbread = new FoodDrink("Garlic Bread", 4.99, Global.itemtype.STARTER);

        FoodDrink burger = new FoodDrink("burger", 7.99, Global.itemtype.MAIN);

        fullList.add(cola);
        fullList.add(pepsi);
        fullList.add(lemmonade);
        fullList.add(burger);
        fullList.add(garlicbread);



    }


    public ObservableList<FoodDrink> filterByType(Global.itemtype itemtype){
        ArrayList<FoodDrink> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FoodDrink listItem : fullList){
            if(listItem.getItemtype().equals(itemtype)){
                subList.add(listItem);
            }
        }
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(subList);
    }



    //plain old main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SelectDrinkController fbtd = new SelectDrinkController();
        //System.out.println(fbtd.filterByType("DRINK"));

        FoodDrinkController fdc = new FoodDrinkController();
        //System.out.println(fdc.filterByType(Global.itemtype.DRINK));

    }
}
```

Comment: table.setRunningTotal(table.getRunningTotal() + selectedItem.getPrice());

Comment: Though it would be better if Table had an addToRunningTotal(double price) method.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thank you very much. For testing purposes right now im just trying to print the current value to the console but it just doesnt. Ive tried System.out.println(tbl.getRunningTotal()); but i just get a huge error?

Comment: Actuall i fixed that, but it doesnt seem to add to the actual running total to test it i printed the get running total method butit stays the same even when i add more items

Comment: Try System.out.println("" + tbl.getRunningTotal()); If this fails to get the correct response, I suggest running it in a debugger. BlueJ has a very simple debugger that would probably work for you. Also, if you have an error and stack trace, you might paste them into the question so we can help with it.

Comment: We'd have to see more code than you've shown us so far to help with this.

Comment: Ok ill edit the question to include more code

Comment: Wouldnt this code just set the running total to the price or im i confused
tbl.setRunningTotal(tbl.getRunningTotal() + selectedItem.getPrice());

Currently if im adding something thats 3 twice the total is 3 does this just set it and not add to it?

Comment: public void addPriceToRunningTotal(double price) {runningTotal += price;}  This adds the price to the running total.

Comment: @NomadMaker Which class should i put this in 
The table class?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an assignment. If you have questions about the language to help you do the assignment fine, ask away (in fact 'search' they've probably already been answered). But Stackoverflow is not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes, the class that stores and handles the running total should be the one that has the method to increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating another instance of the `Table` every time you add an entry.

You want to create the `Table` once (I'm guessing.)  Probably in the constructor of `SelectDrinkControllerGUI`:

You already have an instance variable `table` in `SelectDrinkControllerGUI`, so just change your constructor to:

```
public SelectDrinkControllerGUI() {
    this.table = new Table();
}
```

Then update `addEntry(...)`:

```
public void addEntry(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    FoodDrink selectedItem = lvDrinks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    fdc.order.add(selectedItem);

    table.setRunningTotal(table.getRunningTotal() + selectedItem.getPrice());

    System.out.println(table.getRunningTotal());

    System.out.println(fdc.order);
}
```

Also, you don't need the `"" +` to print out doubles.  Just do what I did above:

```
System.out.println(tbl.getRunningTotal());
```

Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: THAT WORKED!! THANK YOU

Comment: No problem!  If you want you can also take @NomadMaker's advice and create an `addToRunningTotal(double price)` to make it cleaner.